# Are the Shoreditch Board of Guardians records for St. Leonards Workhouse online anywhere?

Tags: ancestry.com, united-kingdom, london, archives, poor-law-records

I'm trying to find information on someone who was born in October 1910 at 204 Hoxton Street, Shoreditch (London, UK) which I have come to learn was the [St. Leonards workhouse and hospital](http://www.workhouses.org.uk/Shoreditch/).

The short question is - where could I find records of him and his mother for this?

At the [National Archives page for St. Leonards](https://search.lma.gov.uk/scripts/mwimain.dll/144/LMA_OPAC/web_detail/REFD+H19~2FSL?SESSIONSEARCH) it directs you to the LMA. But I've read older forums of people accessing the records online there? Has this now stopped?

At the London Metropolitan Archives for [St Leonards Hospital H19/SL](https://search.lma.gov.uk/scripts/mwimain.dll/144/LMA_OPAC/web_detail/REFD+H19~2FSL?SESSIONSEARCH) it says

> "For the administration of Shoreditch Workhouse and Infirmary 1867-1930 and for registers of inmates in the workhouse and infirmary see the records of Shoreditch Board of Guardians"

On the [LMA page for that collection](https://search.lma.gov.uk/scripts/mwimain.dll/144/LMA_OPAC/web_detail/REFD+SHBG~2F149~2F027?SESSIONSEARCH) it says that all the records are available on Ancestry.co.uk.

The records I think I want are:

Register of patients, males 1906 00-1910 SHBG/149/013
Register of patients, males 1910 00-1912 SHBG/149/012
Register of patients, female 1908 -1912 SHBG/149/027

but I'm finding it confusing to locate these records online. I've recently done other research on the Islington Workhouse and this made much more sense. I'm wondering if the Shoreditch records were either partially lost or destroyed, or whether Ancestry hasn't finished putting them online? **UPDATE:** all records a labelled as "Physical Condition: Fit" by the LMA.

I know some of these are not transcribed, and I've been browsing the images manually.

Ancestry in this case doesn't have the above references, it uses a USA code, so it's hard to correlate the sources except by name.

I've got a premium membership (not sure if it alters which catalogues are available?), but when I look at the list of catalogues, there doesn't seem to be a Guardians section like there is for the other workhouses.

[image]

[image]

If you browse the Shoreditch records, you get some of the name-indexed admissions records - which I've come to understand were a recompilation of the primary book which itself was in date order as people arrived and departed.

[image]

However this only goes up to 1903.

Scrolling down there is an "other" section which does go through 1910, but when I browsed through these images (under G mostly) while there are hundreds of entries for 1908 and other years, suddenly there are only three or four names in 1909, 1910, 1911. Then picks up again in 1912/1913, but it's not like there's pages missing in the archive, it's more like the hospital was closed during this period? They were still recording admissions but only very few.

[image]

It's frustrating - as all the records seems to skip exactly the year I'm looking for!

Looking at the last 1903 book, it does have the LMA reference on a sticker on the book. I want SHBG/149/012 and 13, it does seem like the next two books are simply not on Ancestry?

[image]

I have also asked Ancestry, but they seem slow to reply.

Comment: Hi, could you add to your question the name AncestryUK gave to the database or over-arching collection shown in your screenshots? Or if you would like to compare what the US Card Catalog says, simply log in with your existing credentials to AncestryUS, ignoring any prompt that advises you that you should be logging in closer to home.

Comment: @JanMurphy yes I think that's the point of my "answer" when I wrote the question I wasn't paying attention to the where I'd started searching from. I didn't think that affected it. However (see my part answer) I now understand the categories that show up in the drop-down selections, are modified by the context they are displayed. I remember those options being on the bottom left of the screen - which I think are just during the basic search you can choose to browse the collections instead.

Comment: When you say Ancestry US, do you mean the .com address? It seems the .co.uk site frequently redirects there anyway, so I always end up using a mix of both without realising.

Comment: Yes. E.g. the Card Catalog is here: https://search.ancestry.com/search/cardcatalog.aspx#ccat=hc%3D25%26dbSort%3D1%26sbo%3D1%26

It's not safe to assume that the search results will be the same no matter where your starting point is.

Answer (score 4):

I found one of the three (SHBG/149/013) under "Miscellaneous" of course after digging around for a while longer. I'm glad I previously noticed the LMA sticker on the 149/11 book - I knew to look for it this time.

[image]

I found it made more sense to browse from the four poor law categories which have their own dedicated search pages. <strike>I came to suspect that the documents are "tagged" and therefore can show up in multiple lists.</strike> (no, if they are in multiple lists they appear to be re-added separately, as sometimes they are mixed with different books even).

1. [Workhouse Admission and Discharge Records, 1764-1930](https://www.ancestry.co.uk/search/collections/londonadmindisch/)

   - Hackney > Shoreditch : Nothing relevant to me (dates/places)
   - Hackney > St Leonard : Nothing relevant just 1789.
2. [Poor Law Hospital Admissions and Discharges, 1842-1918](https://www.ancestry.co.uk/search/collections/londonhospitalregisters/)

   - No Hackney/Shoreditch
3. [Selected Poor Law Removal and Settlement Records, 1698-1930](https://www.ancestry.co.uk/search/collections/lmapoorlawsettlement/)

   - <strike>Buggy! Broken selection goes to a collection/0 error page</strike> UPDATE: They've fixed it, Aug 2019.
   - This does now have interesting Shoreditch records like Visitor Books (with my family listed). But not the patient records.
4. [Poor Law and Board of Guardian Records, 1738-1930](https://www.ancestry.co.uk/search/collections/lmapoorlaw/)

   - Has Hackney > Hackney, Hackney Guardians, Shoreditch. All have similar lists, A&D, Deaths, Children, Religious Creed etc.
   - Shoreditch

     - A&D:

       - Inf/St. Leonards < 1865-1903
       - Other paupers  1851-1916 (as mentioned, sketchy around 1910)
     - Miscellaneous:

       - More Infirmary/St Leonards overlapping - e.g. 1901-1906, 1898-1906 probably different types of records. But not for 1908-10
       - **Register of Patients, Males, 1906-1910  - AHA!**

[image]

However my ancestor is not there as this book only goes to 5th Jan 1910.

Looking through the entire collection, I have made a "map" of Ancestry names to LMA references. However it's still missing the other two references I am looking for.

```
Hackney; Shoreditch; Admission and Discharge:

"Infirmary Later St Leonards Hospital, Hoxton Street, 1865-1877" (119i) = SHBG/149/008
"Infirmary Later St Leonards Hospital, Hoxton Street, 1872-1881" (138i) = SHBG/145/1
"Infirmary Later St Leonards Hospital, Hoxton Street, 1872-1883" (57i) = SHBG/149/015
"Infirmary Later St Leonards Hospital, Hoxton Street, 1874-1877" (234i) = SHBG/149/018?
"Infirmary Later St Leonards Hospital, Hoxton Street, 1877-1879" (95i) = SHBG/149/017
"Infirmary Later St Leonards Hospital, Hoxton Street, 1878-1887" (87i) = SHBG/149/005
"Infirmary Later St Leonards Hospital, Hoxton Street, 1880-1881" (58i) = SHBG/149/002
"Infirmary Later St Leonards Hospital, Hoxton Street, 1881-1883" (61i) = SHBG/149/003
"Infirmary Later St Leonards Hospital, Hoxton Street, 1881-1888" (204i) = SHBG/145/2
"Infirmary Later St Leonards Hospital, Hoxton Street, 1891-1894" (263i) = SHBG/146 "Porter's Register"
"Infirmary Later St Leonards Hospital, Hoxton Street, 1902-1903" (39i) = SHBG/149/11 "Male Patients Register"


Hackney; Shoreditch; Miscellaneous:

"Infirmary Later St Leonards Hospital, Hoxton Street, 1874-1877" = SHBG/149/18 (12i) "Patients Register". Empty/Incomplete scan 
"Infirmary Later St Leonards Hospital, Hoxton Street, 1876-1884" = SHBG/149/1 (91i) 1881-1884
"Infirmary Later St Leonards Hospital, Hoxton Street, 1877-1881" = SHBG/149/4 (97i) 1877-1880
"Infirmary Later St Leonards Hospital, Hoxton Street, 1882" (56i) = SHBG/149/16 "Parish of St. Leonards Shoreditch Infirmary Female Patients Register" A:1878-1881
"Infirmary Later St Leonards Hospital, Hoxton Street, 1882" = SHBG/149/19 MaleRegister (67i) A:1882-1884
"Infirmary Later St Leonards Hospital, Hoxton Street, 1887" (255i) 
  i1 = SHBG/149/6 "Shoreditch Infirmary Male Register 1887 to" 1887-1890
  i159: Second Book! = SHBG/149/20 Female Register
"Infirmary Later St Leonards Hospital, Hoxton Street, 1890-1891" (23i) = SHBG/150 "Address of Patient's Friends" visitor book 1990.02-1891.09 
"Infirmary Later St Leonards Hospital, Hoxton Street, 1890-1893" (93) = SHBG/149/22 Female 1890.05-1893.02
"Infirmary Later St Leonards Hospital, Hoxton Street, 1890-1894" (90i) = SHBG/149/7 Male Patient Register 1892.11-1894.11
"Infirmary Later St Leonards Hospital, Hoxton Street, 1892-1894" (74i) = SHBG/149/22 Female 1889/1892-1894
"Infirmary Later St Leonards Hospital, Hoxton Street, 1894-1898" (70i) = SHBG/149/23 Infirmary Female Patients Register
"Infirmary Later St Leonards Hospital, Hoxton Street, 1894-1899" (100i) = SHBG/149/9 Infirmary Male Patients Register.
"Infirmary Later St Leonards Hospital, Hoxton Street, 1895-1902" (71i) = SHBG/149/24 Infirmary Female Patients Register.
"Infirmary Later St Leonards Hospital, Hoxton Street, 1897-1903" (39i) = SHBG/149/25 Infirmary Female Patients Register.
"Infirmary Later St Leonards Hospital, Hoxton Street, 1898-1906" (86i) = SHBG/149/14 Male Patients Register. 1902-1906
"Infirmary Later St Leonards Hospital, Hoxton Street, 1899-1902" (424i) = SHBG/145/003 "A&D" "13-12-1899 to 10.6.1902". 
"Infirmary Later St Leonards Hospital, Hoxton Street, 1900-1902" (94i) = SHBG/149/10 "Male Patients Register" 1892-1902.2
"Infirmary Later St Leonards Hospital, Hoxton Street, 1901-1906" (68i) = SHBG/149/26  Female Patients Register. 1901.3-1906.3
```